# AS3 printing the lowest value to a dynamic textfield

Tags: actionscript-3

```
var a:Object =({label:"2008",n:8560,i:15909});
var b:Object ={(label:"2009",n:8146,i:14197});
```

Lets say I have five objects similar to this in a list component. Is there possible to have a function that prints out the label of the item which has the lowest value n ? What would I have to do to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sort on the field you want first (n in this case) using [Array.sortOn()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Array.html#sortOn()), then access it and print:

```
var arrayToSort:Array = [{label:"2008",n:8560,i:15909},{label:"2009",n:8146,i:14197}];
var sortedArray = arrayToSort.sortOn ("n" , Array.NUMERIC);
trace(sortedArray[0].label);
```

Comment: I tried this but it doesn't work correctly. The trace shows 2008 but the n value of 2008 is more than 2009.

Comment: ooopse, updated, it should array numeric (ascending) if you want to access the first element. Array.DESCENDING isn't wrong either, just select the last element [array length -1 ] instead of 0

Comment: Thanks it works perfectly now, but there is one thing i don't understand.. Why is n typed as a string inside the sortOn?

Comment: lookup associative arrays in actionscript. with your code from the top, you can access the n property as ```a.n``` but also ```a['n']``` which is how the sortOn function will be able to access the property

Comment: I will do that. Thank you so much for all your help :)

Comment: If you don't mind I have another small question very related to this.. lets say I wanted the array to sort by the values of n+i how would this work? I tried 
`var sortedArray = arrayToSort.sortOn ("n" + "i" , Array.NUMERIC);`but this does not work..

Comment: ```"n" + "i"``` are computed on the fly in this case and ```sortOn()`` will not be able to handle it as you expect. (It will try to sort on the resulting string, ```ni``` which is not a property of your object). When you put these objects together, you can add an ```ni``` field yourself. Otherwise, at the end of appending elements to the array, you can use a for loop or [forEach()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Array.html#forEach()) to add this summed filed. ```for(var i = 0 ; i < arr.length; i++) arr[i]["ni"] = arr[i].n + arr[i].i;```

Comment: ...or ```arr.forEach(function(item:*,index:int,a:Array){
 item["ni"] = item.n + item.i;   
});
```

Comment: I thought it was weird that  "n" + "i" didn't work,thank you for explaining it to me. That forEach method was really neat didn't know about it. My program now works 100% as intended thank you very much for everything :)

Comment: glad it worked. if you have the time, be sure to checkout the rest of the actionscript 3.0 language reference for the Array class (and the examples provided there). I'm sure on the long run you'll run into situations needing most the methods available

Answer (score 0):

```
public function findMax( o:Object ):String {
    var lowest:Number = Number.MAX_VALUE;
    var lowestLabel:String;
    for (var label:String in o) {
        var val:Number = o[label];
        if ( val != null && val < lowest ) {
            lowest = val;
            lowestLabel = label;
        }
    }
    return lowestLabel;
}
```